# Htaccess. Bitrix. Редирект со старых папок на тестовые

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, редирект

Всем доброго дня!
Имеется довольно большой интернет-магазин на битриксе. Нужна была новая версия, под старый функционал.
Есть копия этого магазина, с подключенным новым дизайном. Разработка нового сайта велась отдельно, но были затронуты многие старые компоненты. Т.е. недостаточно залить новый шаблон чтобы сайт заработал.

Перенос сайта планирую сделать следующим образом - заливать рядом папки с новой версией, допустим папка /bitrix/ и рядом /bitrix2/ и переключаться между ними, таким образом имея возможность быстро откатить изменения.

Суть вопроса: можно ли как-нибудь средствами битрикса или настройкой .htaccess перенаправлять запросы на новые папки, которых будет примерно полтора десятка? Так было бы гораздо удобнее, вместо поочередного переименовывания всех папок.

Пробовал это, битрикс ругается

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bitrix/(.*)$ /bitrix2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Гуглил, читал мануалы, но не смог найти ничего полезного. Проблема скорее всего в том, что не могу правильно и коротко сформулировать вопрос.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Стандарт де-факто для таких телодвижений -- переключение симлинка.

Ваш DOCUMENT_ROOT является ссылкой на каталог проекта. Переключили ссылку на другой каталог проекта, сделали релоад веб-сервера -- переключились.

Рабочий вариант -- сделать еще один vhost, который смотрит на папку проекта с редизайном. Upload разместить отдельно, чтобы он был доступен в проектах по ссылке. Проверить, что всё корректно работает, и переключить симлинк. Никаких редиректов, никаких переименований.